# C++ : How does creating an object on stack within a loop works under the hood?

Tags: c++, loops, object

Suppose I have a code like this : -

```
struct myStruct{

    int a;
    int b;
};

int main(){

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){

        myStruct obj; 
        cout<<"Address of object in memory : "<<&obj<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Does this actually creates 5 different objects on the stack? If so why does the it prints the exact same memory address everytime considering that obj is the actual object and not a reference to the object? I have read a few answers here on the site but I am still not able to understand it completely.

Comment: It re-uses the same space for each one, which is why you see the same address

Comment: *Stack* is an implementation detail (compiler implementation). It is not dictated by the C-language standard (which doesn't even define what a stack is). So every compiler vendor is free to do what they choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object `obj` is created at the start of each iteration, and destroyed at the end.

If you place output statements in its constructor and destructor, you will be able to see that happening.   (Although, technically, the compiler is free to elide objects if the only way of detecting their existence is to track constructor and destructor calls, most compilers probably won't in this case, since the alternative would be reinitialising the object at the start of each iteration).

You will also be able to see this by adding an extra scope.

```
int main()
{

   for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
   {
      {   // extra scope here
          myStruct obj; 
          cout<<"Address of object in memory : "<<&obj<<endl;
      }
      obj = something();   //   will not compile since obj does not exist here
   }

   return 0;
}
```

With compilers that use the stack (an  implementation detail, not required by the standard), there is a fair chance that additional variables will not be placed on the stack between the end of one iteration and the start of the next.  That would explain you seeing all the objects having the same address.

Answer (score 2):

If you got the same address printed out, that just means the memory space is reused, doesn't mean they're the same objects.

If you add a user-defined constructor (and destructor) you'll see 5 different objects are constructed (and destructed):

```
struct myStruct{

    myStruct() { std::cout << "ctor\n"; }
    ~myStruct() { std::cout << "dtor\n"; }

    int a;
    int b;
};
```

Potential result:

```
ctor
Address of object in memory : 0x7fffc5be8c50
dtor
ctor
Address of object in memory : 0x7fffc5be8c50
dtor
ctor
Address of object in memory : 0x7fffc5be8c50
dtor
ctor
Address of object in memory : 0x7fffc5be8c50
dtor
ctor
Address of object in memory : 0x7fffc5be8c50
dtor
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/CJMU41013)

Answer (score 0):

Does this actually creates 5 different objects ***on the stack***?

Yes, it does create 5 different objects. Whether it creates it on stack or not is a different thing. **All it says is, in the every iteration of `for` loop a new object will be created statically.** Now, when an object is created statically it has a predefined scope and lifetime which is decided at compile time itself. For the instance `myStruct obj;` the scope is `for` loop. Whether you get the same or different address for the instance in every iteration is implementation defined.

Also, **every object has an identity of its own** which can be verified by the fact that they are newly created (as specified in other answers). Also, this **identity** is defined by combination of object's scope, lifetime, name. Now, this **identity** cannot be an address of the object.